# Structuring DB tables and @Relation to create a questionaire from db entities? (kotlin, Room)

Tags: kotlin, android-room

Iam seeking a little guidence before diving into a new project.

My aim is to produce a form/questionaire within an app that pulls **Question** data, based on a question's **Group** and its **Category**. Where each Category contains many Groups, and each Group contains many Questions.

To support the UI and nested recycler views, the intent was to provide the viewmodel with a **single object** that contains nested lists. i.e An object with a list of Categories, containing a list of Groups, containing a list of Questions.

In terms of setting up room, entities and DAOs, and their relationships, my understanding is that that the best way to achieve this is to:

- Create a Questions entity (conatining text,options..etc.)
- Create a reference table for the relationship between Questions and Groups (many-to-many)
- Create a parent/child table for the relationship between Groups and Categories (one-to-many)

Following this a set of relation based data classes should be use to marry up each pair.

- GroupWithQuestions data class (using @Relation to list questions in each group using the reference table)
- CategoryWithGroupsWithQuestions data class (using @Relation to list groups in each category using parent/child table)
- QuestionaireWithCategoriesWith...Questions data class (containing a list of CategoryWithGroupsWithQuestions)

This is complicated, relationships need to be followed through multiple tables, and thus will be hard to update and time consuming to resolve errors. I feel like Im over thinking the approach (or am missing something).

**Is there a simpler/smarter way?**

(Is the single object approach part of the problem?)

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create a Questions entity (conatining text,options..etc.)
> Create a reference table for the relationship between Questions and Groups (many-to-many)
> Create a parent/child table for the relationship between Groups and Categories (one-to-many)

A one-many simply needs a column in the child for the parent.

> This is complicated, relationships need to be followed through multiple tables, and thus will be hard to update and time consuming to resolve errors. I feel like Im over thinking the approach (or am missing something).

This isn't really that complicated: I believe the following is pretty close to what you appear to be asking for:-

**Entities**

**Category** :-

```
@Entity(
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["categoryName"],unique = true) /* Assume that a category name should be unique */
    ]
)
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey
    val categoryId: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo
    val categoryName: String
)
```

**Group** :-

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Category::class,
            parentColumns = ["categoryId"],
            childColumns = ["categoryIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)

data class Group(
    @PrimaryKey
    val groupId: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val categoryIdMap: Long,
    val groupName: String
)
```

- Foriegn Key constraints are not necessary but they help to enforce referential integrity.

  - onDelete and onUpdate aren't necessary but can be helpful

**Question**

```
@Entity(
)
data class Question(
    @PrimaryKey
    val questionId: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val questionText: String,
    val questionOption: Int
)
```

**QuestiongroupMap** (could be GroupQuestionMap) :-

```
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["questionIdMap","groupIdMap"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Question::class,
            parentColumns = ["questionId"],
            childColumns = ["questionIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Group::class,
            parentColumns = ["groupId"],
            childColumns = ["groupIdMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class QuestionGroupMap(
    val questionIdMap: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val groupIdMap: Long
)
```

**POJO's**

**GroupWithQuestions**

```
data class GroupWithQuestions(
    @Embedded
    val group: Group,
    @Relation(
        entity = Question::class,
        entityColumn = "questionId",
        parentColumn = "groupId",
        associateBy = Junction(
            QuestionGroupMap::class,
            parentColumn = "groupIdMap",
            entityColumn = "questionIdMap"
        )
    )
    val questionList: List<Question>
)
```

- via the QuestiongroupMap and hence the association and Junction

**CategoryWithGroupsWithQuestions**

```
data class CategoryWithGroupWithQuestions(
    @Embedded
    val category: Category,
    @Relation(entity = Group::class,entityColumn = "categoryIdMap",parentColumn = "categoryId")
    val groupWithQuestionsList: List<GroupWithQuestions>
)
```

- **NOTE** even though you are getting a List of GroupWithQuestions, it is the Group entity that is specified.

Some extras that may be of use :-

```
data class CategoryWithGroup(
    @Embedded
    val category: Category,
    @Relation(entity = Group::class,entityColumn = "categoryIdMap",parentColumn = "categoryId")
    val group: Group
)

data class GroupWithCategory(
    @Embedded
    val group: Group,
    @Relation(entity = Category::class,entityColumn = "categoryId",parentColumn = "categoryIdMap")
    val category: Category
)
```

**Dao's**

**AllDao** (i.e. all in one place for brevity/convenience) :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(category: Category): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(group: Group): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(question: Question): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(questionGroupMap: QuestionGroupMap): Long
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `group`")
    abstract fun getAllGroupsWithCategory(): List<GroupWithCategory>
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM category")
    abstract fun getAllCategoriesWithGroups(): List<CategoryWithGroup>
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `group`")
    abstract fun getAllGroupsWithQuestions(): List<GroupWithQuestions>

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM category")
    abstract fun getAllCategoriesWithGroupsWithQuestions(): List<CategoryWithGroupWithQuestions>

}
```

an @Database class **TheDatabase** :-

```
@Database(entities = [Category::class,Group::class,Question::class,QuestionGroupMap::class],exportSchema = false,version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    TheDatabase::class.java,
                    "thedatabase.db"
                )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- allowMainThreadQueries for brevity/convenience

Finally putting the above into action in an activity, result in a list of CategoreiesWithgroupsWithQuestions being extracted and output to the log :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        val TAG = "DBINFO"

        val cat1 = dao.insert(Category(categoryName = "Cat1"))
        val cat2 = dao.insert(Category(categoryName = "Cat2"))
        val cat3 = dao.insert(Category(categoryName = "Cat3"))

        val grp1 = dao.insert(Group(groupName = "Grp1",categoryIdMap = cat1))
        val grp11 = dao.insert(Group(groupName = "Grp11",categoryIdMap = cat1))
        val grp111 = dao.insert(Group(groupName = "Grp111",categoryIdMap = cat1))
        val grp1111 = dao.insert(Group(groupName = "Grp1111",categoryIdMap = cat1))
        val grp2 = dao.insert(Group(groupName = "Grp2",categoryIdMap = cat2))
        val grp22 = dao.insert(Group(groupName = "Grp22",categoryIdMap = cat2))
        val grp3 = dao.insert(Group(groupName = "Grp3",categoryIdMap = cat3))

        val q1 = dao.insert(Question(questionText = "Q1 ....", questionOption = 11110000))
        val q2 = dao.insert(Question(questionText = "Q2....", questionOption = 11010101))
        val q3 = dao.insert(Question(questionText = "Q3....", questionOption = 10000001))
        val q4 = dao.insert(Question(questionText = "Q4....",questionOption = 11000001))
        val q5 = dao.insert(Question(questionText = "Q5....",questionOption = 11100011))

        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q1,grp1))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q1,grp2))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q1,grp3))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q2,grp2))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q2,grp22))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q3,grp3))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q4,grp11))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q4,grp111))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q4,grp1111))
        dao.insert(QuestionGroupMap(q5,grp22))

        /* extract the data via the geAllCategoriesWithGroupsWithQuestions query*/
        for (cwgwq: CategoryWithGroupWithQuestions in dao.getAllCategoriesWithGroupsWithQuestions()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Category is ${cwgwq.category.categoryName} ID is ${cwgwq.category.categoryId}, it has ${cwgwq.groupWithQuestionsList.size} groups, which are:-")
            for(gwq: GroupWithQuestions in cwgwq.groupWithQuestionsList) {
                Log.d(TAG,"\tGroup is ${gwq.group.groupName} ID is ${gwq.group.groupId}, it has ${gwq.questionList.size} questions, which are:-")
                for(q: Question in gwq.questionList) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"\t\tQuestion is ${q.questionText} options are ${q.questionOption} ID is ${q.questionId}")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**result** :-

```
D/DBINFO: Category is Cat1 ID is 1, it has 4 groups, which are:-
D/DBINFO:   Group is Grp1 ID is 1, it has 1 questions, which are:-
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q1 .... options are 11110000 ID is 1
D/DBINFO:   Group is Grp11 ID is 2, it has 1 questions, which are:-
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q4.... options are 11000001 ID is 4
D/DBINFO:   Group is Grp111 ID is 3, it has 1 questions, which are:-
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q4.... options are 11000001 ID is 4
D/DBINFO:   Group is Grp1111 ID is 4, it has 1 questions, which are:-
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q4.... options are 11000001 ID is 4
D/DBINFO: Category is Cat2 ID is 2, it has 2 groups, which are:-
D/DBINFO:   Group is Grp2 ID is 5, it has 2 questions, which are:-
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q1 .... options are 11110000 ID is 1
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q2.... options are 11010101 ID is 2
D/DBINFO:   Group is Grp22 ID is 6, it has 2 questions, which are:-
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q2.... options are 11010101 ID is 2
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q5.... options are 11100011 ID is 5
D/DBINFO: Category is Cat3 ID is 3, it has 1 groups, which are:-
D/DBINFO:   Group is Grp3 ID is 7, it has 2 questions, which are:-
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q1 .... options are 11110000 ID is 1
D/DBINFO:       Question is Q3.... options are 10000001 ID is 3
```

Comment: Wow! @miket thats an incredible answer. Thankyou for the time and effort to put in all that detail. Yes you are correct, this is what I was refering to in regards to setting up the entities and relationships. As it is the simpler approach afterall I'll happily proceed and keep learning.